# How to hide model driven app on the Dynamics 365 for phones app?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I have a task: create two model driven apps and both of them must be visible from the PC browser but just one must be visible in Dynamics 365 for phones.

Can you help me with this please?

Comment: I dont understand the reason behind this, but some security role/privilege only can be used for this - as this is not a regular ask

Comment: Hello! Yeah I feel like I should use roles for this, but like I can`t figure out what exactly I should do =(

Comment: Role can be used to control apps between users, but after research I could not find anything to control between clients (browser/mobile)

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for this would be to route all Model-Driven App users to the Dynamics 365 for Phone app and the phone/tablet users to the PowerApps app to use a Canvas App.

Microsoft is trying to focus all phone and tablet users on Canvas Apps rather than Model-Driven Apps. The Model-Driven App is primarily for PCs and really focuses more on keeping users in the proper areas that they have licensing for. As you may have noticed, a user can have a license for just D365 for Sales and yet still be given access to the Cases Entity through a Model-Drive App. This is because the Common Data Model behind the scenes hosts both Entities and does not restrict anything natively. Microsoft used to have the generic interface that allowed access to all Entities but now Model-Driven Apps are supposed to restrict them.

Sorry for the long answer but see if the manager requesting this would allow you to just create one Canvas App and one Model-Driven App as I suspect that is probably what they think they are requesting anyway. The mobile users will have a much better experience with a Canvas App anyway.